# Update Service config file with ArcIms java connector

Tags: java, mxd, arcims, debugging

We are using arcims java connector to create, update, delete services. it works fine for create and delete. However when we try to update the config file of service (ie : mxd file) the new mxd file is not replaced in the ArcImsSite.sez file. Thus when we restart ArcIms, the service is created with the wrong mxd file.

here is a snippet of what we do to update the service :

```
ConnectionProxy connectorProxy = new ConnectionProxy();
connectorProxy.setConnectionType(ConnectionProxy.TCP_ADMIN);
connectorProxy.setHost(arcimsHost);
connectorProxy.setPort(arcimsPort);
connectorProxy.setDisplayMessages(false);

configfile = new FileInputStream(ConstantManager.ENV_DIRECTORY+"configuration.properties");
properties.load(configfile);

int ping = connectorProxy.ping(false);
Site site = new Site();

if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_FIRST_LOGIN) {
    site.setSiteUser(properties.getProperty("ADMIN_AIMS"),
    properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"),
    connectorProxy);
} else if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_OK) {
    connectorProxy.setUsername(properties.getProperty("ADMIN_AIMS"));   
    connectorProxy.setPassword(properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"));                            site.setSiteUser(properties.getProperty("USER_AIMS"), properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"),                          connectorProxy);
} else if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_FAIL) {
LoggerManager.logError(LOG, ConstantManager.BUSINESS_TYPE, null);
throw new BusinessException(AdminErrorMessage.ARCIMS_NOT_AVAILABLE, null);
}

ServiceCollection serviceCollection = ServiceCollection.getServices(connectorProxy);

for (int i = 0; i < serviceCollection.size(); i++) {
  Service aservice = serviceCollection.getService(i);
  // delete the old service
  if (aservice.getName().equals(mapBefore.getMapName())) {
   LOG.debug("\t-->INPUT BUSINESS  LAYER on  updateMap METHOD : suppression du service ");
   serviceCollection.removeService(aservice);

aservice.removeService(connectorProxy);
  }
}

//Here i try to save the site config with site.save(connectorProxy). However the service is //deleted from ArcImsSite.sez file by doing this

//Recreate the connexion
ConnectionProxy connectorProxy = new ConnectionProxy();
connectorProxy.setConnectionType(ConnectionProxy.TCP_ADMIN);
connectorProxy.setHost(arcimsHost);
connectorProxy.setPort(arcimsPort);
connectorProxy.setDisplayMessages(false);
int ping = connectorProxy.ping(false);
Site site = new Site();

if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_FIRST_LOGIN) {
    site.setSiteUser(properties.getProperty(USER_AIMS"),
    properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"),
    connectorProxy);
} else if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_OK) {
    connectorProxy.setUsername(properties.getProperty("USER_AIMS"));    
    connectorProxy.setPassword(properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"));                            site.setSiteUser(properties.getProperty("USER_AIMS"), properties.getProperty("PASSWORD_AIMS"),                          connectorProxy);
} else if (ping == ConnectionProxy.PING_FAIL) {
LoggerManager.logError(LOG, ConstantManager.BUSINESS_TYPE, null);
throw new BusinessException(AdminErrorMessage.ARCIMS_NOT_AVAILABLE, null);
}

//Create the new service. Actually same service as previous but with new mxd file.
Service myservice = new Service();
//.... adding required information to new service
myservice.setConfigFile(mxdFilePath);
myservice.setConfigFileLength(buff.length);
myservice.setConfigContents(bais, true);
//....

//Save current service config
if (!site.save(connectorProxy)) {
throw new BusinessException(AdminErrorMessage.SERVICE_CONFIG_CANT_BE_SAVED, null);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the answer is to use AdminSite class from com.esri.aims.admincore package.

Replace :

```
if (!site.save(connectorProxy)) {
    throw new BusinessException(AdminErrorMessage.SERVICE_CONFIG_CANT_BE_SAVED, null);
}
```

by

```
AdminSite as = new AdminSite("http://" + arcimsHost, alias, login, password);
if (!as.saveSite()){
    throw new BusinessException(AdminErrorMessage.SERVICE_CONFIG_CANT_BE_SAVED, null);
}
```